# Issue with CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms, tabs not showing up for PDF Form

Tags: docusignapi

When I submit the following message to CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms, I am receiving a SOAP fault with the message: "Freeform signing is not allowed for your account because it conflicts with other settings, please place signing tabs for each signer." The Tabs all contain valid form field names that correspond to form fields that exist in the PDF, so I am not sure why the tabs are not being created successfully through the API. When I upload the PDF through the DocuSign UI to create a new envelope, it does recognize the form fields, so not sure why through the API the form fields aren't being created/found. Here is the message:

```
<CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms xmlns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
<EnvelopeInformation>
    <AccountId>--removed--</AccountId>
    <EmailBlurb>Your documents for the Sample Application are available online for viewing and signing.</EmailBlurb>
    <Subject>eSign Request: Client Account</Subject>
</EnvelopeInformation>
<CompositeTemplates>
    <CompositeTemplate>
        <InlineTemplates>
            <InlineTemplate>
                <Sequence>1</Sequence>
                <Envelope>
                    <AccountId>--removed--</AccountId>
                    <Recipients>
                        <Recipient>
                            <ID>1</ID>
                            <UserName>First Last</UserName>
                            <Email>someemail@gmail.com</Email>
                            <Type>Signer</Type>
                            <AccessCode>1111</AccessCode>
                            <CaptiveInfo>
                                <ClientUserId>someemail@gmail.com</ClientUserId>
                            </CaptiveInfo>
                            <CustomFields>
                                <CustomField>167ae5ce-14e4-49b5-93c7-8202f933d6a2</CustomField>
                            </CustomFields>
                            <RoutingOrder>1</RoutingOrder>
                        </Recipient>
                        <Recipient>
                            <ID>2</ID>
                            <UserName>First2 Last2</UserName>
                            <Email>someemail2@gmail.com</Email>
                            <Type>Signer</Type>
                            <AccessCode xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <RequireIDLookup>true</RequireIDLookup>
                            <CaptiveInfo>
                                <ClientUserId>someemail2@gmail.com</ClientUserId>
                            </CaptiveInfo>
                            <CustomFields>
                                <CustomField>bdc98023-3239-4644-8309-606c661c21a0</CustomField>
                            </CustomFields>
                            <RoutingOrder>2</RoutingOrder>
                        </Recipient>
                    </Recipients>
                    <Tabs>
                        <Tab>
                            <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                            <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                            <PageNumber>3</PageNumber>
                            <Type>SignHere</Type>
                            <TabLabel>form1[0].#subform[2].FinancialAdvisorAuthorizedPersonSignature[0]</TabLabel>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab>
                            <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                            <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                            <PageNumber>3</PageNumber>
                            <Type>DateSigned</Type>
                            <TabLabel>form1[0].#subform[2].finandate1[0]</TabLabel>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab>
                            <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                            <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                            <PageNumber>3</PageNumber>
                            <Type>FullName</Type>
                            <TabLabel>form1[0].#subform[2].repname[0]</TabLabel>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab>
                            <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                            <RecipientID>2</RecipientID>
                            <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
                            <Type>SignHere</Type>
                            <TabLabel>form1[0].#subform[1].AccountHolderSignature[0]</TabLabel>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab>
                            <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                            <RecipientID>2</RecipientID>
                            <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
                            <Type>DateSigned</Type>
                            <TabLabel>form1[0].#subform[1].clientdate1[0]</TabLabel>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab>
                            <DocumentID>1</DocumentID>
                            <RecipientID>2</RecipientID>
                            <PageNumber>2</PageNumber>
                            <Type>FullName</Type>
                            <TabLabel>form1[0].#subform[1].clientname1[1]</TabLabel>
                        </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
                </Envelope>
            </InlineTemplate>
        </InlineTemplates>
        <Document>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Name>DocName1</Name>
            <PDFBytes>--removed--</PDFBytes>
            <TransformPdfFields>true</TransformPdfFields>
            <FileExtension>pdf</FileExtension>
        </Document>
    </CompositeTemplate>
</CompositeTemplates>
<ActivateEnvelope>true</ActivateEnvelope>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Turned on DocuSign logging so that I could possibly get some more info about what may be going wrong and it didn't tell me much, unfortunately. The log states: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I even tried to move the Document node within the InlineTemplate/Envelope/Documents node and still got the same response

Comment: At this point if you haven't cracked this you should get in touch with your DocuSign Account Manager and send them the log and have them log a bug on your behalf...